# Created [supplementary-information] tag then discovered [supporting-information] (it didn't show up in the autocomplete). What next? Synonymization?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

I created a [supplementary-information](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supplementary-information) tag and attached it to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/184841/69206). I then discovered that there is a [supporting-information](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supporting-information) tag with 29 questions already.

The earlier tag did not show up in autocomplete quickly enough when I started typing "supple..." for some reason.

Should I change the tag on the new question or leave it in case that helps to make them synonyms? I have never quite figured out how synonymization works.

Comment: If it's the only instance of the tag being used I would just edit to remove it and use the other.

Comment: @BryanKrause the problem I've pointed out here is that the terms "supplementary" and "supporting" are used somewhat interchangeably and yet when I started typing "supplemen..." the synonymous term did not appear in the autocomplete. This is why I have asked about synonymization. Why don't you think that's a good idea?

Answer (score 6):

Changing the tag on your question would destroy the newly created tag (in the daily clean-up) and thus solve any issues you created.

However, I concur that this is a standard case for a synonym. As I don’t see any potential controversy, I created the synonym and added [supplement](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supplement) and [appendix](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appendix) as further synonyms for good measure.

> I have never quite figured out how synonymization works.

There is a [user-initiated process](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) for it, but it’s so impractical that you might as well ignore it and have the mods do it (by asking a question on Meta like you did).

Comment: "Mods are great, mods are good, let us thank them for our tags, amen." Thanks for you help!

Comment: @uhoh: Do I sense a hint of irony there? Or is this [Poe’s law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe%27s_law) inverted?

Comment: Oh just the opposite! Anybody who can understand things I can't is at least a minor deity to me. It's sort-of an extension of [Arthur C. Clarke's third law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws). I'm elated that SE is so well moderated and works so well.

Comment: @uhoh: Mind that this has little to do with understanding, but privileges granted by the system.